# Synonym request for TMDb-api and TheMovieDb-api

Tags: support, status-declined, synonym-request

Yesterday I've created the tag [tmdb-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tmdb-api) but now I see there is already an tag that's the same [themoviedb-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/themoviedb-api). Can anyone create a tag synonyms for that?

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a need for synonyms, you should just have instead not created the tag as the help center tells you:

> Most common tags already exist on a mature site. **You should always favor existing tags**; only create new tags when you feel you can make a strong case that your question does cover a new topic that nobody else has asked about before on this site.

> As a general rule, you should avoid creating new tags if possible, and new users are not allowed to create new tags. Even if you have sufficient reputation, **you should only create new tags when you feel you can make a strong case that your question covers a new topic** that nobody else has asked about before on this site.

Instead, I've retagged the 7 odd questions with this tag, no need to create a synonym.

Comment: I agree that anyone should not create new tags disfavoring existent ones. On another hand, I don't see why he can't ask for a synonym for a tag. This is not future proof.

Comment: @EMBarbosa it is future proof. In 3 years nobody has ever tried to create the other tag. All the [name-space is called `themoviedb*`](https://www.themoviedb.org/documentation/api). There's simply no way that someone will *create* this tag.

Comment: @EMBarbosa it is future proof. In 3 years nobody has ever tried to create the other tag. All the [name-space is called `themoviedb*`](https://www.themoviedb.org/documentation/api).

Comment: tmdb-api is not an uncommon alternative name for this api in my experience.  Maybe I am missing something, but what is the negative impact to have this tag as a synonym

Comment: @psubsee2003 that we don't need it. I removed the tag. There's no more issues. Move on.

Comment: @Braiam the downvotes on your answer suggest that maybe more explanation than "we don't need it" is needed.  I get the point that maybe it shouldn't have been created based on your quotes, but once it is done, why was "we don't need it" the better solution than a synonym.

Comment: @Braiam Well, the first question on [the FAQ](https://www.themoviedb.org/faq/api) is: "What is **TMDB's API**?" And there is another question: "Where can I find more information on **TMDb API**?"

Comment: @EMBarbosa and? What has that anything to do with what I said. FAQ is not *namespace* (the thing of how methods, objects, variables, modules are called) which is our best guidance. Are you going to waste moderator time on something they don't need to get involved?

Comment: @Braiam "and?" - Well, I was just pointing that it is an synonym already used in official documentation. Also, AFAIK, *namespace* is not the only motivation or guide to create a synonym. I'm not wasting time, just saying that OP may have a point. Anyway, I'm moving on from this discussion.

Comment: @EMBarbosa that's not a synonym, that's an abbreviation. Look at the help page for an example of when synonyms should be used: suggest “bike” as a synonym for bicycle. What you are doing is suggesting bc as synonym of bicycle, because some people are too lazy to type the entire word.

Comment: @psubsee2003 data talked, in 3 years, with only ~50 questions and nobody has ever not found the tag. People can disagree, but the fact is that we don't and the moderator sided with this conclusion.